# Having troubles with the refresh of a PHP page using form

Tags: php, forms, http-post

I've the following PHP code

```
<html>

<head>
    <title>
        Test
    </title>
</head>

<body>
    <form name="test" action="<?php echo htmlentities($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); ?>" method="post">
        <input type="text" name="name">
        <br>
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit Form">
        <br>
    </form>

    <?php
      if(isset($_POST['submit']))
       {
        $name = $_POST['name'];
        echo "User Has submitted the form and entered this name : <b> $name </b>";
        echo "<br>You can use the following form again to enter a new name.";
       }
     ?>
</body>

</html>
```

that works fine and echos the text that the user writes in the input text box.

The code should also avoid the `PHP_SELF` exploits (I hope .. )

But if I try to refresh the web page in my Firefox browser an alert appears that tell me

> To display this page, Firefox must send information that will repeat
>   any action (such as a search or order confirmation) that was performed
>   earlier.

any suggestion on how to avoid this?

Comment: Redirect after form submit.

Comment: I need to mantain all in the same page ....

Comment: So redirect to the same page, what's the problem

Answer (score 0):

```
 if(isset($_POST['submit']))
    {
     $name = $_POST['name'];
     echo "User Has submitted the form and entered this name : <b> $name </b>";
     echo "<br>You can use the following form again to enter a new name.";
         echo ("<script>  window.location.href='http://YourPatch.com';</script>");


    }
```

Comment: uhmmm .. I've tried but seems not working ...

Comment: I updated the answer.If you use your patch it is work.